# Creating reviews for a page through facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement, through api facebook, adding a review for a company page. Similar functionality is implemented on the popular service https://business.trustpilot.com/

It is written in api facebook that this is impossible to implement, maybe I’m not looking at the endpoint, please tell me, maybe someone has encountered a similar task?

I look at the documentation on the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/page/ratings

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: But trustpilot.com how it is done, can there be separate agreements with Facebook or all have the same conditions?